Make sure elements break to a new line without gaps
I am adjusting a suggestions box on a website which shows up when using the search function. It can display a maximum of 12 suggestions but depending on the search it can show 1, 2, 3, 4 etc at a time.
I am experiencing a gap I would like to resolve on the right of these suggestions when they break to a new line.
I am using flex and flex-wrap so when the elements hit the right edge it goes onto the next line and it being responsive depending on screen size. However there is always a gap on the furthest right when elements do break to the next line.
Right space when line breaks 
So I thought of using justify-content: space-around/space-between/space-evenly which does a great job of sorting this gap out but only if the suggestions go down another level. If there are less suggestions, there is a massive gap between them to fill out the available space.
Less elements fill out all available space
More elements sit nicer 
So what I am trying to do is make the elements left align but not have the gap on the right when it breaks to a new line.
Please could anyone assist and if I would need to supply more information as this is my first question.

Given your image I'd suggest that CSS-Grid might be a better option here.

@Paulie_D Thanks. I did try Grid and while it did help with the right gap, it didn't help the layout spacing when there are less suggestions. It looked like the 'Less elements fill out all available space' image but I would like it left aligned.
